# Is it necessary to add index to latitude and longitude fields

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, geocoding, rails-geocoder

I am using `rails` and `geocoder` gem with `postgres` database. Therefore I have to add the `latitude` and `longitude` fields to database. So generally speaking isnt it better to add *indexing* to those fields for faster querying?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you end up querying database for records using latitude and longitude, you'll definitely benefit from adding an index. Indexes will be used not only for exact matching queries, but also for comparison queries, such as `select * from table_name where latitude between 30 and 40 and longitude > 50`.
Depending on the queries and the number of records, postgres query planner will choose the most optimal way to find matching records (either sequential scan, or index scan).

Comment: When searching based on only one field its ok. As here we are indexing both making me confused...Isn't it bad?

Comment: It's not bad. Also you may consider using a single multicolumn index on latitude and longitude instead of having two separate indexes, but in that case you have to make sure that you queries use the same order of columns as in the index. For example, if you create index like this:
`CREATE INDEX test_multi_idx ON test (latitude, longitude);`, your queries should be `... WHERE latitude ... and longitude`, otherwise the index will not be used

Comment: Thank you for the info..Any known articles or tutorials regarding this??

Comment: Postgres has a very good documentation. You can read about indexes at http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/indexes.html